# Catching syntax exception eval() function php laravel5

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me.

```
        $a = 4;
        $b = 6;
        $str_formula = '$a + ';
        $result = null;
        try {
            $math_string ="\$result = ".$str_formula.";";
            eval($math_string);
        } catch (ParseError $e) {
            \Log::info('Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()) ; 
        }
```

I can't get error syntax in controller.however when I try with "tinker". this working. tell me why.

If not, please help me get log. Error Laravel :

```
local.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected ';' { ...
```

I don't want to see the error 500. That is really bad. I am sorry for my bad English,

pls, understand. Thank you.

Comment: Try to catch `\ParseError` class instead of `ParseError`. This may help

Comment: thank you for you instruction (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\ParseError` class for catching instead of `ParseError`.

If you are using `ParseError` this is interpreting as [Your current namespace]\ParseError, but you need `ParseError` from the root namespace.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is a language construct and not a function. This will works. learn more [eval php.net](https://www.php.net/eval)

```
    $a = 4;
    $b = 6;
    $str_formula = '$a + ';
    $result = null;
    try {
        $math_string ="\$result = \"$str_formula\";";
        eval($math_string);
    } catch (ParseError $e) {
        \Log::info('Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()) ; 
    }
```